# Peer assisted networking P2P

Tags: streaming, live, p2p

I was looking for live streaming platforms where you can broadcast yourself and get some money for it. Checked out Streamup, YouNow and AmberDog. The last one was the easiest to use in my perspective but when the stream is loaded, it asks the following:

> Peer assisted networking
>
> amber.dog may use peer assisted networking. Do you want to allow
>   access to your upload bandwidth?

What the hell is that? I haven't seen such a message in any other live-stream platform. Should I allow or deny it?

Comment: sry, here's the link http://amber.dog

Answer (score 0):

They are using RTMFP protocol for live-streaming. No harm.

The stream is sent from one peer (source) to another (origin) directly and the server only organizes the graph - who sends what to whom. In this case, by agreeing, you only allow the stream coming to your flash player to be sent over to the next watcher. This is basically the future of live-streaming.